# Is this a gaming.SE scrape?

Tags: discussion

http://b.vniup.com/index.php/gamer/old-racing-multiplayer-browser-game-with-weapons.html

compared to

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50081/10260

Sure looks like someone scraped g.se without attribution.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Google Chrome warns me about a "malicious site" if I go to the root url of that address. Why am I not surprised...

Answer (score 6):

You can post "Scrape sites that rank higher on Google than g.se" here:

[Report high-Google-ranking Stack Exchange content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Apparently it is a rampant problem, as you can see (and contribute to) in [an answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers).

Comment: I did report that particular site in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/149411) back in December.

Comment: That post was many many months ago

Comment: @badp The question's old, but the answer's still being updated (as recently as Feb. 8th). There's a link in the answer as well to the one Resorath posted. Tristan *did* already add vniup.com there in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121167/149411) the other day.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I have poked Rebecca about it, all I can do now is sit back and wait